# Is there any a way to query the availability of token symbol?

Tags: symbol-name

Is there any a way to query the availability of token symbol?  I want to issue a token, and I believe the token should be unique among eos network, for example, I cannot issue a new token with name of "EOS", so is there any API to query all token symbols and check the availability of selected one?

Comment: It seems token symbol name is not globally unique. You can issue your own EOS.

Comment: OK, if that is the case, does a token has relationship with the mainnet of chain?  If I (or anyone else) issue another EOS token, I assume we cannot use it to get resources from main net.

Comment: In most places, the token is actually treated as pair (token symbol, contract name): it is usually a bug to check the token name but not the contract name. So (EOS, eosio.token) is different from (EOS, otheraccount).

Comment: Still, I second the question, as naming tokens as the same symbol will, at best, cause confusion for users and exchanges.